How to provide PATH for `gtest_discover_test` in CMake?
I used the following CMake command to add a test executable.
add_executable (CurveTest)
target_sources (....)
target_link_libraries (CurveTest PRIVATE error string)
gtest_discover_tests (CurveTest)

where error and string are imported dlls.
But when I built the project, CMake says
Error running test executable.
Path: path/to/CurveTest.exe
Result: Exit code 0xc0000135

I found this is because that CurveTest.exe (in ./Exec/CurveTest.exe) is in a dir different from error.dll (in ./Basic/error.dll) and string.dll (in ./String/error.dll). After copying these files to ./Exec, everything just went fine.
Could someone tell me how to tell CTest to execute CurveTest.exe with 2 extra env PATH, ./Basic and ./String?
